# nginx different backends static files cache

Tags: nginx, cache

I have 3 servers in my test environment:

- Linux running nginx
- Win running IIS with ASP app
- Linux Running Apache with PHP.

I'm trying to setup static files caches. Servers 2 and 3 have absolutely different content.
Here is my cache config:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=static_cache:100m inactive=120m max_size=900M;
proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
```

and here is the main config file of nginx:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  _;

   proxy_read_timeout             600s;
   proxy_send_timeout             600s;   

   location /foo/ {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_pass      "http://192.168.11.11:8888/foo/";
    proxy_set_header X-debug-message-foo request_method|$host|$request_uri|$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
   }


   location /bar/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_pass      "http://192.168.11.10:8885/bar/";
    proxy_set_header X-debug-message-bar "$request_method|$host|$request_uri|$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";

   }

    location ~* ^.+/foo/.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz) {
        expires 60d;

        proxy_pass http://192.168.11.11:8888;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache static_cache;
        proxy_cache_key "$request_method|$host|$request_uri";
        proxy_cache_valid 1d;
  }

  location ~* ^.+/bar/.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz) {
        expires 60d;

        proxy_pass http://192.168.11.10:8885;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache static_cache;
        proxy_cache_key "$request_method|$host|$request_uri";
        proxy_cache_valid 1d;
  }
}
```

So my point is to create cache with static files for different locations and if cache is out of date nginx must load content from the backend server (not from local server's root).
Unfortunately `sudo ls -la /var/cache/nginx` shows me that cache directory is always empty.

Also I tried how the cache works only for one backend site by changing location like this

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz)
```

and

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.11.11:8888;
```

In this case the foo locations cache works well and cache folder is not empty. Of course the 'bar' location does not serve any static files.

UDP

Finally I figured out.
The only working solution is using nested location context.
Like in this example:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  _;

   proxy_read_timeout             600s;
   proxy_send_timeout             600s;   

   location /foo/ {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_pass      "http://192.168.11.11:8888/foo/";

        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz) {
            expires 60d;

            proxy_pass http://192.168.11.11:8888;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache static_cache;
            proxy_cache_key "$request_method|$host|$request_uri";
            proxy_cache_valid 1d;
      }
   }


   location /bar/ {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_pass      "http://192.168.11.10:8885/bar/";

        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz) {
            expires 60d;

            proxy_pass http://192.168.11.10:8885;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_cache static_cache;
            proxy_cache_key "$request_method|$host|$request_uri";
            proxy_cache_valid 1d;
      }

   }
}
```

Please keep in mind if your backend server is not in subdirectory (e.g. directly in public_html directory not like this public_html/foo) you need to remove double subdirectory by using `rewrite /foo(.*) /$1  break;` inside nested location context.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems wrong.

`^.+/foo/.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz)` cannot match url like `/foo/test.jpg` but only urls like `/t/foo/test.jpg`.

`+` means one or more times.

Comment: Regex `location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|gz)` is nested location of `location /foo/ ` so it trying to find out url after /foo/

Comment: Yes, the regex in the second configuration file looks good.